# A 'HttpGet' request forces a close

Tags: android, response, http-get

I use the following code, and when I click a button it force closes. I want to read the response from a web page and show it in a messagebox or a edittext or anything else.

How do I fix this problem?

#### Code

```
    HttpGet request = new HttpGet("http://www.google.com");
    HttpClient client = null;
    HttpResponse resp = null;
    try {
        resp = client.execute(request);
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    HttpEntity entity = resp.getEntity();
    MessageBox("Response : "+entity.toString());
}
```

Comment: Post the stack trace and make sure you aren't doing network operations on the main (UI) thread, which it seems you might be doing.

Comment: What version of Android are you using? Because I may have an answer..\

Comment: From the code it seems you initialise ``HttpClient client = null`` and then call ``client.execute(request)``. Should you initialise ``HttpClient`` with something else than ``null``?

Comment: @harism is correct here, the current code definitely will definitely throw a `NullPointerException` on the line `resp = client.execute(request)`... And once that's fixed you'll get the problem shown in the answer by Ramesh Sangili, assuming you aren't currently running in a background thread of some type

Answer (score 4):

You are trying to run the HTTP request in your UI code. That's why you got a *Force Close*. Please try to run it in a service, AysncTask or Thread so the UI thread will not be blocked.

Please refer the example *[Android HTTP Request in AsyncTask](http://brainking.info/archives/615-Android-HTTP-Request-in-AsyncTask.html)*.

Comment: This is classed as best practice in 2.3 and below I believe. Depending on his platform this answer is correct.